# Implicitly create associated model from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Post that has_many :tags

I want to do:

Post.create({:tags => ['tag1', 'tag2']})

How can I make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom setter method on the `Post` model, like so:

```
def tags=(ts)
  ts.each {|tag| self.tags.create(Tag.new(:tag => tag)) }
end
```

or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Might be able to do that with [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I'd like to be able to use an array of strings directly, and I'd also like it to associate with the existing object if there is one.

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to add a virtual attribute to your Post model and create the tags in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [acts-as-taggable-on](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end

Post.create(:tag_list => ['tag1', 'tag2'])
```